# If positive mass distorts spacetime (spacetime gets curved toward the object) then would a theoretical negative mass make spacetime bulge out?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass

So lets assume for this question that negative mass exists then will a theoretical planet made of negative mass create an outward bulge in spacetime to create antigravity (repulsive). Also for this question use this image to represent spacetime curvature created by positive mass (Basically regular attractive gravity). I thought that negative mass would make spacetime bulge in the opposite outward direction.[image: 4 dimensional representation of general relativity (the accurate one)]

Comment: To have that effect you do not need negative mass - negative pressure in gravastar has the same effect, see Fig. 10 in paper "Surface Tension and Negative Pressure Interior of a Non-Singular `Black Hole' " (https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03806) by Pawel O. Mazur and Emil Mottola.

Comment: But does it create antigravity ? My main question is if it creates antigravity or not ?

Comment: It is gravity caused by pressure that in contrast to mass can become negative. Hence my answer to your main question is not, it is not antigravity.